# Immutable.JS filter a collection in a deeply nested Collection filterIn

Tags: functional-programming, immutable.js

I'am using Immutable.JS and try to filter a list which is nested in a parent collection, without using a variable.

Here an example with cars collection:

```
{
  { 1 => {
    id:'1',
    licencePlateNumber: 'BT 226 FQ',
    passengers: ['John', 'Marie', 'Edward'],
  },

  { 2 => {
    id:'2', 
    lice...
    ...
  },
}
```

Edward got upset and do not want go in week-end with us anymore, here the new collection i want.

```
{
  { 1 => {
    id:'1',
    licencePlateNumber: 'BT 226 FQ',
    passengers: ['John', 'Marie'],
  },

  { 2 => {
    id:'2',  
    lice...
    ...
  },
}
```

In order to do that I can write:

```
const removePassenger = (carsCollection, carId, removedPassenger) => {
    const passengers = carsCollection
      .getIn([carId, 'passengers'])
      .filter(pName => pName !== removedPassenger)

    return (carsCollection.setIn([carId, 'passengers'], passengers))
}
```

Which i found very ugly as a functionnal programmer. Instead of that would i prefer use a function 'filterIn' like this.

```
const removePassenger = (carsCollection, carId, removedPassenger) => {

    return (carsCollection
      .filterIn([carId, 'passengers'], pName => pName !== removedPassenger)
}
```

Does a function like this exist ? Found nothing doing that in the doc.